# javascript .innerHTML() inserts outside div

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table and a button, when the button is pressed it adds a new input into the table inside a div, when I add the input manually inside the div and test it it works, but when the script adds it it goes outside the table.. why is that? how can i fix this issue?

html:

```
..
<script> var x=0; </script>
...
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td>From:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="from" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>To (email):</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="to0" /></td>
           <td><input type='button' onclick='newMail()'  value='Add recipient'/> </td>
         </tr>

    <div id="add">
        <tr>
           <td>To (email):</td> <!-- this works -->
           <td><input type="text" name="to0" /></td>
        </tr>
    </div>

         <tr>
           <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="send"></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
```

JS:

```
 function newMail()
 {
    x=x+1;
    var input =
    "   <tr>"+
    "      <td>To (email):</td>"+
    "      <td><input type='text' name='to"+x+"' /></td>"+
    "    </tr>";
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += input;
 }
```

the function works and adds the input and everything, but it goes outside the table, whilst the one inside the div that i manually added works fine and is displayed normally.

Comment: A div as child of a table element isn't valid

Comment: You can't mix table and non-table layout like that.    You could use a `<tbody>` instead of a `<div>`, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this please

```js
function newMail() {
  x = x + 1;
  var input =
    "   <tr>" +
    "      <td>To (email):</td>" +
    "      <td><input type='text' name='to" + x + "' /></td>" +
    "    </tr>";
  document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += input;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var x = 0;
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>From:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="from" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>To (email):</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="to0" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>To (email):</td>
    <!-- this works -->
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="to0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="add"></tbody>

  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <input type="submit" value="send">
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <input type='button' onclick='newMail()' value='Add recipient' />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: This would put the added content at the end of the table, not above the 'submit' row.

Comment: @DanielBeck i fixed it.

Comment: i never knew about the <tbody> tag, this helps a lot! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/0dh52827/

JAVASCRIPT

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#add_recipient").click( function() {
        x = x + 1;
        console.log(x);
      var input =
        "   <tr>" +
        "      <td>To (email):</td>" +
        "      <td><input type='text' name='to" + x + "' /></td>" +
        "    </tr>";
      $("#add").prepend(input);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script>
  var x = 0;
</script>
<table id="add">
  <tr>
    <td>From:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="from" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>To (email):</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="to0" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>To (email):</td>
    <!-- this works -->
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="to0" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <input type="submit" value="send">
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <input id="add_recipient" type='button' value='Add recipient' />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

JQUERY Prepend is designed for things like this.

Comment: this would add it at the top, it is supposed to be near the end.
but i learnt something new, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The element with id="add" is a `<div>` in a `<table>` (which is not properly placed but might work in some browsers). Adding code to it has at least an undefined behavior.

You should instead remove the `<div>` tag and give the `<tr>` tag the id="add" attribute and then use `document.getElementById("add").appendChild()` method to add a new html node. To create this node, don't use text but `document.createElement()` like described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)